# android Cloud database

Tags: android, database, server, cloud

which language is used to write an android sever(the server on the web)?
I mean the server that sends the information to the android app from the web(not sharedpreferences or any local database)
is that server different from the website server?
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is client-server architecture. Server does the processing and presents information to the client. A client can be a web browser,an app or many other things.
Android is used for building apps. Which means it is used to build client. To build backend server, you use server side languages and/or frameworks. Some common languages/technologies used to for web application development: Java,PHP,Node.js,C# and so on